# What's the difference between app.config and app.manifest for .NET?

Tags: .net, winforms, projects-and-solutions

Not sure if this is just specific to Winforms projects (this is the project that I'm making) but I'm just wondering the difference between the two. I am making high-dpi changes that only apply to Windows 10 Creator's Update and had to edit both.

Comment: Nothing in common, the .config file configures .NET, the manifest configures the operating system.  Winforms has several dpiAware bug fixes, they have to be explicitly turned on in the config file because they were worried about breaking programs that already fixed them by themselves.